# Node express Api parses Post request JSON as null

Tags: node.js, express, axios, mern, body-parser

I'm creating an application that uses the Mern stack, I've managed to successfully send a POST request from the react frontend to the endpoint using axios. See the code below from my react front end, this is from a form posting the signup credentials on the button click function.

```
//Register form in react, onclick handler
 handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const{fname, lname, email, password} = this.state;
    const loginObj = { fname: fname, lname: lname, email: email, password: password};
    console.log(loginObj);

 axios.post('http://localhost:8000/post/members', loginObj);
}
```

the parameter from my form populates these state values and when checking the request payload I can see the same values sent to the console from the LoginObj object.

`router.post('/members', getMembers); // this is my route endpoint calling the getMembers function imported`

```
//The method called by the endpoint
export const getMembers = (req, res)=>{
       console.log("you called me ");//this is displayed on the console when the request is sent
       console.log(req.body);// this returns {} no matter what data is sent is the POST request
    }
```

I'd like to be able to store the values from the post request and read and write to my database. To do these I'd first need an API that could sufficiently interpret the values in the POST Request, can anybody see from the above why I might not be able to read any values from the body of the request?

Comment: If you are using express why you want to stringify the request? The request is already a javascript object, you just need to access the properties without parse anything. You can access the body of your request with `req.body`.

Comment: Sorry, that's something I was just trying to see if it would make a change. Even without stringifying the `req.body` it gives the same output. For clarity of the question I'll remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because you didn't set the parser middleware in your express server.
You can try using the built-in json parser from express. (reference: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.json)

```js
app.use(express.json())
```

If this is not enough, you can try sending the content type header on your request:

```js
axios.post('http://localhost:8000/post/members', loginObj, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried the `app.use(express.json())` but when the error continued remembered I was using a Router instance and replaced it with `router.use(express.json())` which solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In express we need a body-parser middleware to to extracct the entire body portion of an incoming request and expose it on req.body

so i think you need the body-parser package and everything will work fine here is how to install it a set it up

```
 npm i body-parser
```

In you index.js in the server :

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json({extended:true}))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
```